# template inside html mustache js

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, mustache

I'm using `mustache` to render portion of **html**. To do this , I'm using this javascript :

```
   var template = $("#div_name").html();
   ..
   ..
   $("#container").append(Mustace.render(template,some_object));
```

As the `<div id="div_name"></div>` still remain inside the html , I use it only to get a template i was  wondering : is it convenient to keep templated `div` html be inside the `html` or is better to `load` it e.g. with partials through `ajax` ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can also keep templates inside script elements like so:

```
   <script type="application/mustache" id="div_name">
       //Mustache template code here
   </script>
```

And fetch the template code from there using `$("#div_name").html()`. It won't be shown on the page and the script tag is not executed because of the invalid `type`.

Comment: First of all , thank you. I have never seen this kind of solution , but usually I avoid the use of HTML inside javascript because it frequently throws up error , caused by blank spaces. Am I doing wrong?

Comment: @steo yes, like I explained, you should specify `type` like I did. The browser will not execute it as javascript if you specify a type like `application/mustache`. See here, no errors: http://jsfiddle.net/nZQ32/

Comment: what if I have more than one template? I have to create one script for each one?

Comment: @steo Yes, that's what you'd have to do with any solution.